# Movement across a plane to reach a specific place the fastest with optimization calculus.

Tags: calculus, geometry, derivatives, optimization

So there is this rectangular area, $3km$ wide by $8km$ long. $A$ is at the top left hand corner of the area. $B$ is the bottom right hand corner. $C$ is the top right hand corner and $D$ is some point that lies on $BC$.

I have to find the quickest way to get from $A$ to $B$ when traveling across the area can be done at $6 km/hr$ while travelling along the perimeter can be achieved at $8 km/hr$

So essentially I have to derive an equation to get to $B$ from $A$ and minimise the time it will take to travel across the area to get to such point.

So far i have figure that $AD = \sqrt{3^2 +x^2}$ where $x$ is the distance of $CD$ and $DB=8-x$. However how am i supposed to make an equation to minimise the time when all i have are distance values?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: $time=distance/speed$

Comment: So i should write $ADB$ as $$t(x)=\frac{1}{6}(\sqrt{9+x^2})+\frac{1}{8}(8-x)$$

Comment: This is how I would write it

Comment: sweet, thanks for your help